# $A \to B$ with $A$ regular imply that $B$ is CM

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, flatness, local-rings, cohen-macaulay-rings, regular-rings

The answer to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/296971/what-has-projectiveness-to-do-with-cohen-macaulay-rings/297320#297320) question says the following:
"The general statement is if $A \to B$ is finite and injective, and $A$ is noetherian and regular, then $B$ is CM if and only if $A \to B$ is flat.

The if part is easy because $A$ is CM. Locally a regular sequence of $A$ is again a regular sequence in $B$. As a finite injective ring homomorphism preserves the dimensions, $B$ is CM.

The converse is harder but is standard. See for instance EGA IV 6.1.5.".

> **Questions (each question is independent of the others):**
>
> **(1)** I have not found this result in EGA iv 6.1.5 (there is no such iv 6.1.5).
> Could one please refer to this result in EGA or elsewhere?
>
> **(2)** What if we weaken the condition that $B$ is a finitely generated $A$-module to the condition that $B$ is a finitely generated $A$-algebra? I guess the result does not hold anymore, but maybe a weaker version of it still holds?
>
> **(3)** If, in addition to the assumptions, $A$ and $B$ are local rings and $A \to B$ is a local homomorphism, could we weaken '$B$ is a finitely generated $A$-module' to '$B$ is a finitely generated $A$-algebra' and obtain the same conclusion?
>
> **(3)** Is it possible to replace '$A$ regular' in the assumptions by '$A$ is CM' and get the same conclusion or a similar one?

Thank you very much!

Comment: For (1) I believe you should find the result in EGA IV, part 1, Corollaire (17.3.5).

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: For (2), think about $A = k$ a field. Then flatness is automatic, and there is of course no easy criterion to detect whether a $k$-algebra is CM. Maybe a natural hypothesis for the general case would be that all the fibres $B \otimes_A \kappa(\mathfrak p)$ for $\mathfrak p \subseteq A$ prime are CM, but I'm not sure if this is sufficient. (It is necessary when $A$ is regular, as $B \to B \otimes_A A/\mathfrak p$ is a regular immersion since $A \to A/\mathfrak p$ is .)

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn, thank you very much for your comment. Interesting.

Comment: What if $B$ equals $A \times (A/I)$, where $I$ is generated by a regular sequence?

Comment: @JasonStarr, thank you. Did you mean that this is a counterexample for (2)?

Comment: @user237522. "Did you mean that this is a counterexample for (2)?"  That is a counterexample to the quote in your first pargraph.

Comment: Thank you. Please, what if $B$ is assumed to be an integral domain? (I had that assumption in mind, but have not mentioned it).